# Can't install npm package "decap-cms-app" (ETARGET)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, decap-cms

I have an Astro project where i want to install the `decap-cms-app` package in order to manually configure my project.
Currently i'm importing the code using the cdn

```js
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/decap-cms@^3.0.0/dist/decap-cms.js" is:inline></script>
```

When i try to install using npm i get a list of warnings and

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for decap-cms-widget-date@^2.5.7.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

The `date widget`, according to docs, is deprecated. I'm not familiar with how npm works internally but i think the issue is that this package is still trying to import a file that does not exist anymore.
This same error appears when i try to install the regular `decap-cms`.

I have already tried deleteting the node_module folder and cleaning the cache, but the error persists.

Comment: What command did you use for installing the package?

Comment: i tried `npm i decap-cms-app --save` and `npm i decap-cms --save` (with and without `--save` too)

Comment: What Node version are you using?

Comment: node: v18.17.1
npm: 9.6.7